# How to pull up data written between seperators?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, notepad++, sql

I am a digital marketer with zero experience at coding.

I'd like to pull up only the first data which is written between separators (|||)

```
[VP/NNP] ||| talk here ||| walk here ||| PPDB2.0Score=6.03040 PPDB1.0Score=1.919110 -logp(LHS|e1)=7.19109 -logp(LHS|e2)=0.42834 -logp(e1|LHS)=15.32573 -logp(e1|e2)=0.49145 -logp(e1|e2,LHS)=5.83537 -logp(e2|LHS)=9.49919 -logp(e2|e1)=1.42766 -logp(e2|e1,LHS)=0.00883 AGigaSim=0.91193 Abstract=0 Adjacent=0 CharCountDiff=-1 CharLogCR=-0.03077 ContainsX=0 Equivalence=0.182028 Exclusion=0.008591 GlueRule=0 GoogleNgramSim=0.52732 Identity=0 Independent=0.187394 Lex(e1|e2)=62.90141 Lex(e2|e1)=62.90141 Lexical=1 LogCount=0.69315 MVLSASim=NA Monotonic=1 OtherRelated=0.000021 PhrasePenalty=1 RarityPenalty=0.00005 ReverseEntailment=0.621966 SourceTerminalsButNoTarget=0 SourceWords=6 TargetTerminalsButNoSource=0 TargetWords=6 UnalignedSource=0 UnalignedTarget=0 WordCountDiff=0 WordLenDiff=-0.16667 WordLogCR=0 ||| 0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 5-5 ||| ReverseEntailment
```

**Result:**

```
talk here ||| walk here
```

How to achieve this result using notepad++ or Microsoft word or excel?

Answer (score 4):

#### Using Notepad++

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^|]*\|{3}([^|]*\|{3}[^|]*).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  [^|]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a pipe
  \|{3}       # 3 pipe character
  (           # group 1
    [^|]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a pipe
    \|{3}       # 3 pipe character
    [^|]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a pipe
  )           # end group
  .*          # 0 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

If you want to do it by Excel, put your data on cell `A1`, and paste the following function on any cell:

```
=MID(A1,
FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5,
FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5)+5)-FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)-5
)
```

You can refer to the following image for clarification.

[image: Steps]

**Also:** If you want to process, say, 500 data like this:

1. Put your data on `A1-A500`.
2. Paste the function on `B1`.
3. Copy `B1` and paste on cells `B2-B500`.

In that way, `Bx` will have the processed data of `Ax`.

## How I Constructed the Function

A weird thing about Excel is, it counts index from 1 instead of 0.

Keeping that in mind, we have:

| Cell | Content | Function | Reduced Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `A1` | `input` | - | - |
| `B1` | `delimiter` | - | - |
| `C1` | Index of char after the first delimiter | =FIND(B1,A1,1)+5 | =FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5 |
| `D1` | Index of char after the second delimiter | =FIND(B1,A1,C1)+5 | =FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5)+5 |
| `E1` | Index of char after the third delimiter | =FIND(B1,A1,D1)+5 | =FIND(" ||| ",A1, FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5)+5) +5 |
| `F1` | Characters between the first and the third delimiters | =MID(A1, C1, E1-C1-5) | =MID(A1, FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5, FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)+5)+5)-FIND(" ||| ",A1,1)-5) |

And we have the function!

However, if I was using this Excel file, I would not reduce functions like this. Instead, I would keep columns `B-E` as hidden, and view the outputs in `F`. This gives us more flexibility, and the code remains understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `FILTERXML` (your input in A1):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ||| ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

It splits the string using the separator `|||` and returns an "array", for which you can access the elements using `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ||| ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),2)
```

It returns "talk here". you can do the same for getting "walk here":

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ||| ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),3)
```

and concatenate both, for instance using `TEXTJOIN`

Comment: Where have you seen that the data is XML formatted? Moreover the result must be `talk here ||| walk here`, not only `talk here`

Comment: 1. have you tried it? if you did then you will have observed that the input does not need to be XML formatted. 2. okay, I edited